# Defer body.close after receiving response

Tags: go

```
......
resp, err := httplib.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
......
```

Is it necessary to close the response body every time?

Comment: Yes. If you don't do so, the sender doesn't get the information that you closed the connection. Not closing the body may leak file descriptors.

Comment: Just for curiosity: What in the documentation is unclear here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Quoting from the official documentation of the [http package](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/):

> The client must close the response body when finished with it

Answer (score 11):

Contrary to the top-voted answer: yes, it *is* necessary to close `resp.Body` *whether you consume it or not*.

This is a good question, and the docs are very misleading here.  In [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/148riho42sU) of the official Go forums, the diagnosis and conclusion -- which I have experienced for myself -- is:

> I was leading to leaking open files on the server, so I confirm, you MUST close the body, even if you don't read it

Comment: It's not at all misleading. If "you don't intend to read it" then you are "finished with it" and must close it.

Comment: @DaveC That is the explanation I have given, too... but only after I knew the answer.  Most Go developers don't know they must close the response Body (I keep fixing bugs in open source code whose author didn't realize this), even after reading the docs, and the phrasing is ambiguous, which is why I say the docs are misleading.

Comment: If someone said to you, "when you're done with the bathroom, wash your hands," does that mean you should wash your hands whether or not you've used the bathroom?  I think not.

Comment: But what about AWS Lambda that will die anyway?

Answer (score 6):

> **`What happens if we do not close the response body ?`**

It is a resource leak. It can remain open and client connection will not be
reused.

It is recommended to close immediately after checking the error.

```
client := http.DefaultClient
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

From the http.Client documentation:

> If the returned error is nil, the Response will contain a non-nil Body
> which the user is expected to close. If the Body is not both read to
> EOF and closed, the Client's underlying RoundTripper (typically
> Transport) may not be able to re-use a persistent TCP connection to
> the server for a subsequent "keep-alive" request.
>
> The request Body, if non-nil, will be closed by the underlying
> Transport, even on errors.

**What is RoundTripper ?**

It is a Transport specifies the mechanism by which individual
HTTP requests are made.If nil, DefaultTransport is used.

Comment: Is there not a resource leak if you return nil, err before you can get to the defer statement?

Comment: @CalebRobinson, in case of error, there is nothing to close, resp will be nil or something else unusable.